# how to use cp,mv and cd commands in python program

Tags: python, csv

when I am executing following code in Jupyter notebook I got error

```
File "<ipython-input-1-69ae760fc196>", line 11
    cd hp1.csv
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

what should I do to remove the error

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()    
df = spark.read.csv("hp.csv")
ds=df.select('_c3')    
ds.write.csv('hp1.csv')    
cd hp1.csv    
mv *.csv hp2.csv    
cp hp2.csv /home/priya/project    
cd ..
```

Comment: python is not a shell language... to do what you want you need `os.remove`, `os.chdir` and `shutil.move` `shutil.copy`

Comment: but I want this operations before some python code how can I use it

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new cell for different commands, so, python commands run on their own cells, and the bash commands in separate cells.

cell 1:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv("hp.csv")
ds=df.select('_c3')


ds.write.csv('hp1.csv')
```

cell 2:

```
%%bash
mv *.csv hp2.csv

cp hp2.csv /home/priya/project

cd ..
```

Note the `%%bash` on the beginning of the cell 2, this tells jupyter to use bash syntax.